# Is there a way to create a data type that only accepts a range of values?

Tags: types, rust

I have a function that takes an argument of type `u16`. Is there an elegant way to define a custom data type that behaves exactly like a `u16` but only has values between 0 and 100?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<s>As I understand it, that requires [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which Rust does not have.</s>  This doesn't require dependent types (see comments) but Rust still doesn't have the support needed.

As a workaround, you could create a newtype that you verify yourself:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Age(u16);

impl Age {
    fn new(age: u16) -> Option<Age> {
        if age <= 100 {
            Some(Age(age))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let age1 = Age::new(30);
    let age2 = Age::new(500);

    println!("{:?}, {:?}", age1, age2);
    assert_eq!(
        std::mem::size_of::<Age>(),
        std::mem::size_of::<u16>()
    );
}
```

Of course, it doesn't behave *exactly* like a `u16`, but you don't want it to, either! For example, a `u16` can go beyond 100... You'd have to reason out if it makes sense to add/subtract/multiply/divide etc your new type as well.

For maximum safeguarding, you should move your type and any associated functions into a module. This leverages Rust's visibility rules to prevent people from accidentally accessing the value inside the newtype and invalidating the constraints.

You may also want to implement [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) (from `u16` to your type) or [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) (from your type to `u16`) to better integrate with generic code.

An important thing to note is that this newtype takes the same amount of space as a `u16` - the wrapper type is effectively erased when the code is compiled. The type checker makes sure everything meshes before that point.

Comment: This is more or less what I was guessing I'd have to do. I think for my behavior I would just want clamping actually. So it's fine if they provide other values, but anything above 100 would get clamped to 100.

Comment: It does not require Dependent Types, those are for linking symbols (representing runtime values) to type parametric values and are somewhat more complicated. Ada does not have Dependent Types and yet let you define such custom integrals (built-in in the language) and C++ has non-type template parameters to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks! Is there a generic name for this concept? When I ran across it before, I was told it was "dependent types". I'd like to know the real name (if there is one!).

Comment: @Shepmaster: If there is one, I don't know it. In C++ they are called non-type template parameters, which is really language specific...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not 100% safe.

You can still do the following, which bypasses the constraint of the constructor:

let age = Age {0: 500};

I am also interested in a more solid solution to this problem.

Comment: @VagelisProkopiou that’s solved by using Rust’s module system. Place `Age` inside a module and don’t make the field public.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there is no such a thing inside the std crate.

However, you can do it yourself in an optimized manner with the const generics. Example:

```rust
pub struct BoundedI32<const LOW: i32, const HIGH: i32>(i32);

impl<const LOW: i32, const HIGH: i32> BoundedI32<{ LOW }, { HIGH }> {
    pub const LOW: i32 = LOW;
    pub const HIGH: i32 = HIGH;

    pub fn new(n: i32) -> Self {
        BoundedI32(n.min(Self::HIGH).max(Self::LOW))
    }

    pub fn fallible_new(n: i32) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        match n {
            n if n < Self::LOW => Err("Value too low"),
            n if n > Self::HIGH => Err("Value too high"),
            n => Ok(BoundedI32(n)),
        }
    }

    pub fn set(&mut self, n: i32) {
        *self = BoundedI32(n.min(Self::HIGH).max(Self::LOW))
    }
}

impl<const LOW: i32, const HIGH: i32> std::ops::Deref for BoundedI32<{ LOW }, { HIGH }> {
    type Target = i32;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dice = BoundedI32::<1, 6>::fallible_new(0);
    assert!(dice.is_err());

    let mut dice = BoundedI32::<1, 6>::new(0);
    assert_eq!(*dice, 1);

    dice.set(123);
    assert_eq!(*dice, 6);
}
```

And then you can implement the maths, etc.

If you want to chose the bound at runtime, you don't need this feature, and you just need to do something like that:

```
pub struct BoundedI32 {
    n: i32,
    low: i32,
    high: i32,
}
```

You can also use a crate like [`bounded-integer`](https://cmcenroe.me/bounded-integer/bounded_integer/) that allows to generate a bounded integer on-the-fly with a macro.

Comment: Now that const generics are stable, this code actually works without nightly.

Answer (score 8):

With the nightly feature `generic_const_exprs`, it is possible to verify this at compile time:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct If<const COND: bool>;

trait True {}
impl True for If<true> {}

const fn in_bounds(n: usize, low: usize, high: usize) -> bool {
    n > low && n < high
}

struct BoundedInteger<const LOW: usize, const HIGH: usize>(usize);

impl<const LOW: usize, const HIGH: usize> BoundedInteger<LOW, HIGH>
where
    If<{ LOW < HIGH }>: True,
{
    fn new<const N: usize>() -> Self
    where
        If<{ in_bounds(N, LOW, HIGH) }>: True,
    {
        Self(N)
    }
}
```

The error messages aren't the best, but it works!

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = BoundedInteger::<1, 10>::new::<5>();
    let b = BoundedInteger::<10, 1>::new::<5>(); // ERROR: doesn't satisfy `If<{ LOW < HIGH }>: True`
    let c = BoundedInteger::<2, 5>::new::<6>(); // ERROR: expected `false`, found `true`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly, to my knowledge. But you can use a trait to get close. Example, where tonnage is a unsigned 8 bit integer that is expected to be 20-100 and a multiple of 5:

```
pub trait Validator{
    fn isvalid(&self) -> bool;
}

pub struct TotalRobotTonnage{
    pub tonnage: u8,
}

impl Validator for TotalRobotTonnage{
    //is in range 20-100 and a multiple of 5
    fn isvalid(&self) -> bool{
        if self.tonnage < 20 || self.tonnage > 100 ||  self.tonnage % 5 != 0{
            false
        }else{
            true
        }
    } 
}

fn main() {
    let validtonnage = TotalRobotTonnage{tonnage: 100};
    let invalidtonnage_outofrange = TotalRobotTonnage{tonnage: 10};
    let invalidtonnage_notmultipleof5 = TotalRobotTonnage{tonnage: 21};
    println!("value {} [{}] value {} [{}] value {} [{}]", 
    validtonnage.tonnage, 
    validtonnage.isvalid(),
    invalidtonnage_outofrange.tonnage, 
    invalidtonnage_outofrange.isvalid(),
    invalidtonnage_notmultipleof5.tonnage, 
    invalidtonnage_notmultipleof5.isvalid()
);
}
```