# Limit parameter values at compile time

Tags: rust, compile-time

Is there a way in Rust to limit paramter values to a range or condition depending on a generic type?

Given a `T` as unsigned, `u8` or `u16`

```
const fn do_something_with_a_bit_offset<T>(offset: u8) -> T {
    // .. some ops return a T ..
}
```

If `T` is `u8`, offset can be 0..7, offset > 7 should not compile
If `T` is `u16`, offset can be 0..15, offset > 15 should not compile

```
    let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset::<u8>(0);  // OK
    let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset::<u8>(8);  // Compile error
    let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset::<u16>(0);  // OK
    let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset::<u16>(8);  // OK
    let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset::<u16>(16);  // Compile error
```

How can I do this at compile time?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to create a data type that only accepts a range of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673674/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-data-type-that-only-accepts-a-range-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we start, I must mention the obvious: if `offset` is *not* a compile-time constant, there is no way to avoid a runtime check.

If the `offset` parameter is guaranteed to be a compile-time constant, you can use const generics and some [associated constant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants) magic:

```
trait CheckOffset<const OFFSET: usize> {
    const CHECKED_OFFSET: usize;
}

impl<T: MaxOffset, const OFFSET: usize> CheckOffset<OFFSET> for T {
    const CHECKED_OFFSET: usize = if OFFSET <= T::MAX_OFFSET {
        OFFSET
    } else {
        panic!("Invalid offset")    // Compile time panic
    };
}
```

`CheckOffset` is a helper trait that defines an associated constant `CHECKED_OFFSET` which (in its implementation) actually does the offset check. A reference to `<T as CheckOffset<OFFSET>>::CHECKED_OFFSET` will compile only if the given offset `OFFSET` is less than the maximum offset for `T` (`<T as MaxOffset>::MAX_OFFSET`). `MaxOffset` is a helper trait that defines the maximum bit offset for a type:

```
trait MaxOffset {
    const MAX_OFFSET: usize;
}

impl<T> MaxOffset for T {
    const MAX_OFFSET: usize = 8 * size_of::<T>() - 1;
}
```

If you need a function to take in a compile-time checked offset for a given type `T`, you must

1. Add a const generic argument (`OFFSET`) to represent the input offset
2. Add a `CheckOffset<OFFSET>` constraint to the type `T`
3. Use `<T as CheckOffset<OFFSET>>::CHECKED_OFFSET` as the actual offset. If you do not use the `CHECKED_OFFSET` constant, the max offset check in the associated constant implementation will not be evaluated.

```
fn foo<T: CheckOffset<OFFSET> + 'static, const OFFSET: usize>() {
    let offset = T::CHECKED_OFFSET;
    println!("{} Offset: {:?}", type_name::<T>(), offset);
}

fn main() {
    foo::<u8, 0>();
    foo::<u8, 7>();
    // foo::<u8, 8>();      // Compile error

    foo::<u16, 0>();
    foo::<u16, 15>();
    // foo::<u16, 16>();    // Compile error

    foo::<u32, 0>();
    foo::<u32, 31>();
    // foo::<u32, 32>();    // Compile error
}
```

This approach will work for any compile-time const-evaluatable constraint you may have.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ad2672bf6aeacd488f2afb1b9e47da2)

Answer (score 0):

If `offset` is a runtime constant, there is no way to avoid the check in all of the cases, but you can lift the responsibility of verifying it from the function to the caller. This has the advantages that: failure is clearly communicated (via `unwrap()` or such) and when using literals, you can verify it at compile-time.

The idea is to create a struct that represents "value in range":

```rust
mod private {
    pub trait Sealed {}
    impl Sealed for u8 {}
    impl Sealed for u16 {}
}

use std::ops::RangeInclusive;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub trait RangeLimited: private::Sealed {
    const ALLOWED_RANGE: RangeInclusive<u8>;
}

impl RangeLimited for u8 {
    const ALLOWED_RANGE: RangeInclusive<u8> = 0..=7;
}

impl RangeLimited for u16 {
    const ALLOWED_RANGE: RangeInclusive<u8> = 0..=15;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct InRange<T> {
    value: u8,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T: RangeLimited> InRange<T> {
    pub fn new(value: u8) -> Option<Self> {
        T::ALLOWED_RANGE.contains(&value).then_some(Self {
            value,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        })
    }

    pub fn get(self) -> u8 {
        self.value
    }
}

const fn do_something_with_a_bit_offset<T>(offset: InRange<T>) -> T {
    // .. some ops return a T ..
}
```

Usage is like:

```rust
let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset::<u8>(InRange::new(0).unwrap());
```

When using literals (or any const value), the compiler can verify it at compile time and save you an `unwrap()`. For that, we'll need a macro:

```rust
impl<T: RangeLimited> InRange<T> {
    #[doc(hidden)]
    pub const fn new_unchecked(value: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            value,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! in_range {
    ($type:ty, $v:expr) => {{
        const __IN_RANGE_VALUE: $crate::InRange<$type> = {
            const __IN_RANGE_VALUE: $type = $v;
            if !(*<$type as $crate::RangeLimited>::ALLOWED_RANGE.start() <= __IN_RANGE_VALUE
                && __IN_RANGE_VALUE <= *<$type as $crate::RangeLimited>::ALLOWED_RANGE.start())
            {
                panic!("value out of range");
            }
            $crate::InRange::new_unchecked(__IN_RANGE_VALUE)
        };
        __IN_RANGE_VALUE
    }};
}
```

Usage is like:

```rust
let mask = do_something_with_a_bit_offset(in_range!(u8, 0));
```

The `const` is to force the compiler to evaluate it at compile-time, otherwise it'll evaluate it at runtime and it'll be a runtime panic.

If you want to rely on the value being in-range for soundness, you need to make `new_unchecked()` unsafe and add an `unsafe` block around it in the macro (however, be cautious to not also wrap `$v` in the same unsafe block).